# Jersey WAS9 not able to depoy

Tags: jersey, websphere

I am trying to deploy my web application on WAS9 with JDK 1.8 , however it gives a error of CDI

Below is the error

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CannotBindObjectException: Object is not of any type which can be bound. Object type is com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.initialize(CDIExtension.java:196)

I removed Jersey 1.X version from war , but still this error.

In my local it work good with tomcat and same other application runs good in WAS 8

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with Jersey 1.9.  It worked fine in WAS 8, but not WAS 9.  The solution was to add this parameter to the Generic JVM Arguments of WebSphere.

-Dcom.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.lookupExtensionInBeanManager=true

This setting is kind of buried the Admin Console.  The [notes from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/setting-generic-jvm-arguments-websphere-application-server) explain how to access it for various types.

**Application Server**

1. In the Administration Console select Servers
2. Expand Server Type and select WebSphere application servers
3. Click on the name of your server
4. Expand Java and Process Management and select Process Definition.
5. Under the Additional Properties section, click Java Virtual Machine.
6. Scroll down and locate the textbox for Generic JVM arguments.